# Appending elements to a list in a dictionary affects a deep copy

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a copy of a dictionary without altering the original. I have two ways of performing the same task But I don't understand why one may change the original while the other wouldn't:

For example:

```py
input_dict = {
    'a': [],
    'b': []
}

test_list = [1,2]

test_dict = input_dict.copy()
for i in test_list:
    test_dict['a'] = test_dict['a'] + [1]

input_dict
>>> {'a': [], 'b': []}
test_dict
>>> {'a': [1, 1], 'b': []}
```

But when I try to do the same procedure this time using append the result is different

```py
input_dict = {
    'a': [],
    'b': []
}

test_list = [1,2]

test_dict = input_dict.copy()
for i in test_list:
    test_dict['a'].append(1)

input_dict
>>> {'a': [1, 1], 'b': []}
test_dict
>>> {'a': [1, 1], 'b': []}
```

This doesn't make much sense to me since in both cases I'm creating a deep copy.

Comment: Why do you think you're making a deepcopy? From the docs, "dict.copy(): Return a shallow copy of the dictionary." - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy

Comment: Aside from that, in your first example, you are resetting the reference of `test_dict["a"]` and are NOT modifying it in place. In your second example, you are modifying it in place, so anything that references that object will see the change.

Comment: I **neither** case are you creating a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

By default python treats most things as objects. The dictionary you created and the array inside it are objects. And in python object pointers are passed around during operations. 
when you do `a=b` while both are objects they have same pointer hence modification of one is another. That is to say it doesn't make a new copy of b, but points to the same location as b, if both are objects. 
In this example, .append() method modifies the object it was used on, So, all objects pointing to that pointer will be changed; while `+` operator returns the value.
when you did

```
test_dict['a'] = test_dict['a'] + [1]
```

the value assigned to test_dict['a'] is a new array which was returned from the add operator. `__add__`  overloading didn't modify the original value but created a new array and `=` operator assigned that to test_dict['a']. 
Hence, only the append affects the original.

Comment: *Everything* in Python is an object. Also, Python *doesn't have pointers*

Answer (score 0):

`dict.copy()` creates a **ShallowCopy**

For creating a **DeepCopy** use:

```py
import copy 

a = {'abc:'xyz'}
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

For further exploration about ShallowCopy and DeepCopy, have a look [here](https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/)